# Play video backwards

Tags: ios, swift, url, video, avasset

What I want is basically reverse an AVAsset and output video file and I found this link -
 https://github.com/tempire/ReverseAVAsset/blob/master/AVAsset.swift

This is what I did:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerView = AVPlayer()


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(animated)

         let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mov")
         let outputUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSUUID().uuidString)video.mov")

         let originalAsset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
         let reversedAsset = originalAsset.reversedAsset(outputUrl)



         playerView = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: reversedAsset!))
         playerViewController.player = playerView

         present(playerViewController, animated: true) { 
             self.playerViewController.player?.play()
         }

    }


}
```

But its not working and this is what I end up with:

[image]

I think I'm doing something wrong with outputURL, please help if you know what to do

Comment: What does reversing an AVAsset and output video file mean?

Comment: take video and reverse it @ElTomato

Comment: play video backwards @ElTomato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with output URL, this is the correct way to do

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerView = AVPlayer()


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mov")

        //Correct way
        var outputURL: URL?
        do {
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            outputURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(NSUUID().uuidString)newvideo.mp4")

        }

        let originalAsset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
        let reversedAsset = originalAsset.reversedAsset(outputUrl)



        playerView = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: reversedAsset!))
        playerViewController.player = playerView

        present(playerViewController, animated: true) { 
           self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was there in Method: `reversedAsset(outputUrl)`
There we try to write the file with a completion handler, and meanwhile we try to play the asset returned by the same method which is not even completely written on disc.

In order to resolve the issue, You've to wait for the method `reversedAsset(outputUrl)` to finish writing the file.